# How is the one-dimensional inverse discrete Fourier Transform calculated in numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, fft, ifft

I have an array of complex numbers (`waves`), which is ordered in the same way as is returned by `fft`. If I call `ifft` on this array, it returns an approximation of the original samples.

I would like to implement `ifft` myself in python. I've found [the formula of IFFT](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/510/25943). I implemented it, but it looks a bit different from the `ifft` result. I tried to fix it by looking at the [ifft source](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.13.0/numpy/fft/fftpack.py#L282), but that is a heavily optimized version, and I was not able to find out how that works

This is what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from scipy.fftpack import fft

# create samples
data = np.zeros(1024)
for k in range(0, 1024):
    data[k] = np.sin(k/20 * np.pi*2)

# plot original samples
#plt.plot(data)
#plt.show()

# apply FFT on samples
waves = fft(data)

# plot FFT result
#plt.plot(np.imag(waves),'r')
#plt.plot(np.real(waves),'b')
#plt.ylabel('value')
#plt.xlabel('period')
#plt.show()

# 
res = np.zeros(1024)
for k in range(0, 1024):
    val = 0.0
    for n in range(0, len(waves)-1):
        # https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/510/25943
        val += waves[n]*np.exp(-1.j * 2*np.pi * n * k / len(waves)) / len(waves)
    res[k] = val.real


#np implementation
res2 = np.fft.ifft(waves)

plt.plot(data, 'b') # original
plt.plot(res,'g') # my implementation
plt.plot(res2,'y') # np implementation
plt.show()
```

Maybe the zero frequency term and the negative frequency terms has to be handled differently. I am not sure about that, because it is not mentioned in any description of fourier transformation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just two mistakes here:

```
for n in range(0, len(waves)-1):
```

should be

```
for n in range(0, len(waves)):
```

because `range` does not include its upper limit (this, along with 0-based indexing, makes implementing FFT-type algorithms a bit easier compared to Matlab).

Also,

```
val += waves[n]*np.exp(-1.j * 2*np.pi * n * k / len(waves))
```

should be

```
val += waves[n]*np.exp(1.j * 2*np.pi * n * k / len(waves))
```

Sign convention vary; in NumPy, direct transform has -1j and inverse has 1j.

---

Of course, the whole thing is very inefficient, but you probably wanted to write it out in detail for yourself. NumPy's vectorized operations would be used normally, beginning with

```
data = np.zeros(1024)
for k in range(0, 1024):
    data[k] = np.sin(k/20 * np.pi*2)
```

being replaced by

```
data = np.sin(np.arange(1024)/20 * np.pi*2)
```

and similarly for other loops.

Comment: How is it possible to do extrapolation correctly? If I just extend the data array and fill it `for k in range(0,2048)` then there is a sudden drop around 1024: https://i.imgur.com/qk5wNnM.png

Comment: This is a separate, and mathematical question; I suggest asking at [dsp.se], with a clarification of what kind of extrapolation is desired.